# Hide rows with id greater than $number

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I have a php variable and want to hide all rows via css that are greater than the $number.
eg. $number= 12;

```
<style>
#row<?php echo $number?>{
display: none;
}
</style>
```

This would hide only the one row 12.
I want to hide all rows greater than 12.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Why not just have 1 hide CSS class and apply the class to the relevant rows?

Comment: however, it would be best if you were to do this via serverside (echo and a conditional statement), since that will still be revealed in HTML source. *That's up to you.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a loop, and write out the code automatically to the page....

```
<?php

for ($i = $number; $i <= 100; $i++) {
    echo '#row'.$i.' {display: none;}';
}

?>
```

In the above code we start from $number (for example, 12) and go up to 100.  We loop each of the numbers between 12 and 100 and write out our 'hiding' code.

Code example above would return you something like:

```
#row12 {display: none;}
#row13 {display: none;}
#row14 {display: none;}
#row15 {display: none;}
```

Additionally, if you wanted to place that directly within your page, it might look something like this:

```
<?php

echo '<style>';

for ($i = $number; $i <= 100; $i++) {
  echo '#row'.$i.' {display: none;}';
}

echo '</style>';

?>
```

Comment: This is perfect. Thanks!--- echo '#row'.$i.'{display: none;}';

Comment: Oh yes... thanks, getting my languages mixed up (I'll change the '+' to a '.')

Answer (score 0):

For this to work you need an parent div and an browser what supports `:nth-child`

HTML

```
<div class="data">
    <div class="row">row1</div>
    <div class="row">row2</div>
    <div class="row">row3</div>

    <div class="row">row4</div>
    <div class="row">row5</div>
    <div class="row">row6</div>

    <div class="row">row7</div>
    <div class="row">row8</div>
    <div class="row">row9</div>    

    <div class="row">row10</div>
    <div class="row">row11</div>
    <div class="row">row12</div>       

    <div class="row">row13</div>
    <div class="row">row14</div>
    <div class="row">row15</div>       
</div>
```

CSS

```
.data div:nth-child(n+12) {
   display: none;
}
```

see demo http://jsfiddle.net/PY5Fe/101/

Comment: No argument there. However, if the OP is using bootstrap, using `<div class="row">` could cause a problem. Bootstrap uses that exact same syntax. *Just saying* ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Mark the final visible row with a class — something like `finalRow` — and use CSS's [general sibling selector `~`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_selectors):

> The ~ combinator separates two selectors and matches the second element only if it is preceded by the first, and both share a common parent.

to hide all the rows that follow it (this example assumes each row is a `div`; alter as needed, of course):

```
<style>
  .finalRow ~ div {
    display: none;
  }
</style>
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/dh7Lp8vk/. A benefit of this approach is that you can have your client-side Javascript move the `finalRow` class as desired.